# Simple probability problem?

Tags: probability

In a game, the numbers from 1 to 20 are written on tickets and placed in a bag. A player draws out a number at random. He or she wins \$3 if the number is even, \$6 if the number is a square number, and \$9 if the number is both even and square. What is the probability that he wins \$3? The answer is $\frac{2}{5}$, and I'm really confused on how it's not $\frac{1}{2}$. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If the numbers 4 or 16 are drawn, then the player wins $\$9$, not $\$3$. Thus the answer is $1/2-2/20=2/5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4$ and $16$ are both even and square. When you get these two numbers you get \$9. So the probability to win 3 dollars is getting $2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18$. That is $8$ out of $20$ numbers. So the probability to win \$3 is $8/20$ = $2/5$.